# Angular -- Failed to Instantiate Module

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Im trying to figure out the client side of an application. Im using Angular, and when I try to load the page I get

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module Facebook due to:Error[$injector:nomod] Module 'Facebook' is not available! You either misspelled the module name  or forgot       to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument. http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.5/$injector/nomod?p0=Facebook
```

I've downloaded and included angular-route and angular-resource, they all compile before the application.js does, and I've moved my ng-app from html tag to body tag.

Any idea what I can do to get this working? It seems straightforward to get the module to work, but it refuses to.

-application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>    
    <script src="/assets/angular/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/angular/angular-resource.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/angular/angular-route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>      
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %> 
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>          
        <script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
<body ng-app="Facebook">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <%= Time.now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %><br>
    <%= Time.now.strftime("%I:%M:%S") %>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="brand" href="#">Titration</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <ng-view></ng-view>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; IHSDigital 2014</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

assets/angular/app.js

```
var app = angular.module("Facebook", [
    "ngResource",
    "Facebook.controllers",
    "Facebook.services",
    "ngRoute"
    ]);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider
    .when("/facebook/index", { "views/facebook/index.html.erb", controller: "FacebookIndexCtrl" })
    .when("/facebook/new", { templateUrl: "<%= asset_path('facebook/edit.html') %> ", controller: "FacebookEditCtrl" })
    .when("/facebook/:id", { templateUrl: "<%= asset_path('facebook/show.html') %> ", controller: "FacebookShowCtrl" })
    .when("/facebook/:id/edit", { templateUrl: "<%= asset_path('facebook/edit.html') %> ", controller: "FacebookEditCtrl" })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/facebook" });
});

app.config(function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
});
```

application.js

```
//
//= require angular
//= require angular-resource
//= require bootstrap
//= require ./angular/app
//= require_tree ./angular
```

I've tried switching the order files load, checked 50 times for spelling errors, and I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
javascript_include_tag "application"
```

is trying to load file application.js so your angular js file is not even loaded into your html page.

I dont know your project structure so i would use

```
<script src="path/to/your/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or

```
 javascript_include_tag "app"
```